# Dynamically changing the value for height constraint of a Xamarin content view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a ContentView inside Xamarin form. There I have height constraint define for that content view.

```
<gComments:GCommentEntryView x:Name="gCommentEntryView"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=100}"
```

Is there a way that I can change dynamically this value of height constraint via code behind?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
{ 
    RelativeLayout.SetHeightConstraint(gCommentEntryView, Constraint.RelativeToParent(layout => 100));                              
});
```